# React-Native Rendering too early?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm not quite sure what's going on, but it seems that react-native wants to render the app before it's done compiling or something...

GIF of the "error"

[image: GIF of the "error"]

Comment: Can you explain what is rendered early ?

Comment: @Panther look at the gif.. the button on the bottom of the screen and the box at the top keep moving around every time i render the screen

Comment: `react-native` is not rendering early or something. This completely depends on your implementation and logic. Need code access to check the issue. We, suggest you debug.

Comment: @panther What's the first thing you would check?

Comment: i hope the button is positioned absolutely and the position is not calculated properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're talking about elements not showing in the same place every time.

It looks like the render of the maps need to be managed.

So you can place the buttons with absolute or you can wait until the map has rendered until you then render everything else. If you're using React Native maps, use `onMapReady`.

Comment: thanks for your input. This helped a bit, the element bodies stay where they have to, but the text doesn't always get rendered the right place. I made the element bodies aboslute, but i'm using flexbox to make the text stay in the center of the body

Comment: @SofusSkovgaard what text are you trying to render? Is it the 'back' text?

Comment: Yeah. It's just a TouchableOpacity with a Text as a child